# Fitting a 1d vector to SVC linear kernel

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use SVC with the linear kernel for image recognition task. My current data is a 2x5 matrix

```
[['Face 1' 'Face2' 'Face 3' 'Face 4' 'Face 5']
 ['229.0' '230.0' '231.0' '230.0' '230.0']]
```

My second row is my X features, which are pixel intensity value from different images.

My first row is my Y labels which are which face image the pixel was extracted from.
I am trying to input my data into SVC at any costs, whatever it takes.

What i am trying is:

```
    m_array = [[229, 230, 231, 230, 230]]
    faces = []
    faces = np.asarray(['Face 1', 'Face2', 'Face 3', 'Face 4', 'Face 5']).reshape(-1, 5)
    
    data = np.stack((faces, m_array)).reshape(2, 5)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    X = data[1, :]
    Y = data[0, :]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)


from sklearn.svm import SVC
svclassifier = SVC(kernel='linear')
svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I want to test for the recognition rate for those features, but i get the error:

> TypeError: Singleton array array(162) cannot be considered a valid
> collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sklearn is expecting your X_train array to be a two dimensional array like (n_examples, 1) for example and the Y_train to be a 1d array of labels like (n_examples, ).

I reformatted your code to remove some unnecessary steps and fix the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC

m_array = np.array([229, 230, 231, 230, 230])[:, np.newaxis]
faces = np.array(['Face 1', 'Face2', 'Face 3', 'Face 4', 'Face 5'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(m_array, faces, test_size = 0.20)

svclassifier = SVC(kernel='linear')
svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```